# SQL Counting trouble

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, count

I have the following **scenario**:

I need to count how many clients have a status of unpaid. and this count must only show those which have a count `>= 2`. This part I am doing correctly (I think):

```
--SELECTING Client Count
SELECT Client, COUNT(HyphenStatus) as UnpaidCount
FROM CasesFromSimplicity
WHERE HyphenStatus = 'UnPaid' AND FCManager = 'Mike'
GROUP BY Client
HAVING COUNT(HyphenStatus) >= 2
ORDER BY Client ASC
```

I then need to create a table which looks like this for the manager view:

```
+-----------+--------------+----------------+------------+
| FCManager | CountingTwos | CountingThrees | FourOrMore |
+-----------+--------------+----------------+------------+
| Mike      |            2 |              1 |          1 |
+-----------+--------------+----------------+------------+
```

This tells me that My consultant `Mike` has two clients with a `count of 2` and `one client with a count of 3` and `one client with a count of 4`.

I have made the following query at the moment, but this doesn't seem to be working.

```
--Selecting the count for manager
SELECT
FCManager
,(SELECT COUNT(HyphenStatus) FROM CasesFromSimplicity WHERE HyphenStatus = 'UnPaid' AND FCManager = 'Mike' HAVING COUNT(HyphenStatus) = 2) CountingTwos
,(SELECT COUNT(HyphenStatus) FROM CasesFromSimplicity WHERE HyphenStatus = 'UnPaid' AND FCManager = 'Mike' HAVING COUNT(HyphenStatus) = 3) CountingThrees
,(SELECT COUNT(HyphenStatus) FROM CasesFromSimplicity WHERE HyphenStatus = 'UnPaid' AND FCManager = 'Mike' HAVING COUNT(HyphenStatus) >= 4) FourOrMore
FROM CasesFromSimplicity
GROUP BY FCManager
```

Could anyone please tell me what I am doing wrong? Or send me to the right place to read on this. I couldnt find anything while searching. *I have been thinking while posting that I will need a group by in the sub queries, but this would then return more than 1 result and not work?*

I have created a [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/9ce06/1) for you to see my issue Live.

Any help would be appreciated, thanks Mike.

Please let me know if I need to explain this further? I am using `SQL SERVER 2008`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, assuming SQL Server 2005+, you can do:

```
;WITH CTE AS
(
    SELECT  FCManager,
            Client, 
            COUNT(HyphenStatus) as UnpaidCount
    FROM CasesFromSimplicity
    WHERE HyphenStatus = 'UnPaid' 
    GROUP BY FCManager,
             Client
    HAVING COUNT(HyphenStatus) >= 2
)
SELECT  FCManager,
        SUM(CASE WHEN UnpaidCount = 2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) CountingTwos,
        SUM(CASE WHEN UnpaidCount = 3 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) CountingThrees,
        SUM(CASE WHEN UnpaidCount > 3 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) FourOrMore 
FROM CTE 
GROUP BY FCManager
```

[**Here is**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/9ce06/16) the modified sqlfiddle.

Comment: That is awesome! :) Thank you so much. I will have to go read up on this `WITH CTE` you speak of because I have no clue what that does.

Comment: @Mike The CTE (common table expression) in this case is helping with readability only. You could've use a derived table as well (like, instead of `WITH CTE...`, just do `SELECT FCManager..... FROM (the same query that I used in the CTE) .....`)